# Find StockNo in the array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find a value from Array in the Javascript. I have Array called myStockList which has over 5000 records in it. I have variable called myStockNo and I want to check to see if that stock number is in the array. This only works for first StockNo in the array and it stops after that. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
     var myStockNo = '376898';

for (var i = 0; i <= myStockList.length; i++)
    {
        if(myStockNo == myStockList[i])
            {
               alert("StockNo found"); 
            }

    else
            {
                alert("StockNo not found");
                break ;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for that:

```
if (myStockList.indexOf(myStockNo) > -1) {
    alert("StockNo found");
} else {
    alert("StockNo not found");
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried to use your solution but I got this:

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out, hope this works for you...

```
var myStockList=new Array("376891","376892","376893","376894","376895","376896","376897","376898","376899","376898");
var myStockNo = '376898';

for(var i=0; i<=myStockList.length-1; i++)
{
    if(myStockNo==myStockList[i])
    {
        alert("Stock Number Found");
    }
else
{
    alert("Stock Number Not Found");
}
}
```